# PySpark coalesce struct fields inside a struct

Tags: pyspark

I have a struct coming from a data source where the struct fields have multiple possible data types like the following:

```
 |-- priority: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- union: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- int32: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- double: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- union: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- double: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- int32: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_d: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- union: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- double: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- int32: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_e: double (nullable = true)
```

I want to coalesce the struct fields and cast them to a data type which makes the most sense, for instance:

```
 |-- priority: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_c: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_d: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- priority_e: double (nullable = true)
```

If a column is not a struct field inside a struct, the following code works perfectly for what I need:

```
try: 
    cols = [f'{c}.{col}' for col in source.select(f'{c}.*').columns]
    if f'{struct_path}.union' in cols:
        cols.remove(f'{struct_path}.union')
    source = source.withColumn(pc, f.coalesce(*cols).cast(t)) # t is the type I want to cast to
except:
    source = source.withColumn(c, f.col(c).cast(t))
```

I would like to the do the same recursively for a struct where the nested struct fields can have multiple data types. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

`StructField`'s fields are accessible by `fields` property, so what you can do is you can make a loop go through the schema and check every field to see if it's `StructType`

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T

for field in schema.fields:
    if isinstance(field.dataType, T.StructType):
        print(field.dataType.fields)
```

Or if you want to read it recursively

```py
def flatten(schema, prefix=None):
    fields = []
    for field in schema.fields:
        name = prefix + '.' + field.name if prefix else field.name
        dtype = field.dataType
        if isinstance(dtype, T.ArrayType):
            dtype = dtype.elementType
        if isinstance(dtype, T.StructType):
            print(dtype)
            fields += flatten(dtype, prefix=name)
        else:
            fields.append((dtype, name))

    return fields
```